# Parse - Array of pointers - Many to Many relationship query

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have a Many-to-Many relationship between the following tables : `User` and `School`. My users are parents, and they have child(ren) in one or several schools.

I spent a few hours reading about designing Many-to-Many relationships on NoSQL databases. I came to the conclusion that the right way to do it was to only store an array of `User` named `parents` within the `School` table.

In Parse.com, this can be materialized by an array of pointers toward the right `User` object.

Now, I want to retrieve all `School`s for a given parent. Here is How I thought I should do :

```
  var School        = Parse.Object.extend("School");
  var school_query  = new Parse.Query(School);
  var current_user  = Parse.User.current();

  school_query.equalTo("parents.objectId", current_user.id);
  school_query.find().then(
    function(schools) {
      console.log("Success");
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
 );
```

This is returning `POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/School 400 (Bad Request)`, calling the "error" callback, although there exist pointers corresponding to my current user within some `School.parents` array.

What is the correct way to query an array of pointers to retrieve its nesting object only if the array contains the pointer towards the current user?

Comment: You're on the right track, I think.  Can you please describe precisely the "parents" column?  It should be an array of pointers to users, not an array of strings that are user objectIDs.

Comment: Also note, the parse advice for when to use an array of pointers rather than a PFRelation is when the size of the array is small.  I don't think they give much more formal guidance on the definition of small, but I take it to mean <100 elements, the default limit on a query.  Do your schools have many more than 100 parents?

Comment: It is funny you mention this, as I just came across [this Q&A post](https://parse.com/questions/pointer-vs-relation) which mentions your piece of advice. We should remain below 100 subscribed parents per school I would say. I can't know for sure yet but that would be surprisingly good to strike above. 

Many thanks for sharing this tip anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "parents" column on School is an array of pointers, operands to it are objects, not object ids.  Change the equality criterion to:

```
school_query.equalTo("parents", current_user);
```